# Neat way to get and set keys of json column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, getter-setter

I have a model/table with a json column in it as follows

```
t.json :options, default: {}
```

The column can contain many keys within it, something like this

```
options = {"details" : {key1: "Value1", key2: "Value2"}}
```

I want to set and get these values easily. So i have made getters and setters for the same.

```
def key1
  options['details']&.[]('key1')
end

def key1=(value)
  options['details'] ||= {}
  options['details']['key1'] ||=0 
  options['details']['key1'] += value 
end
```

But this just adds lines to my code, and it does not scale when more details are added. Can you please suggest a clean and neat way of doing this?

Comment: `options['details']&.[]('key1')` Clever way to use the safe operator!

Comment: @Tom clever way would be to use `Hash#default_proc` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Yes, that would be one way.  Using the long form of `Hash#[]` so that the safe operator can be used shows a good understanding of Ruby.  I wanted to point it out as neat little trick that wouldn't usually be thought of.

Answer (score 3):

Use dynamic method creation:

```
options['details'].default_proc = ->(_,_) {{}}
ALLOWED_KEYS = %i[key1 key2 key3]

ALLOWED_KEYS.each do |key|
  define_method key do
    options['details'][key] if options['details'].key?(key)
  end
  define_method "#{key}=" do |value|
    (options['details'][key] ||= 0) += value
  end
end
```

Comment: `define_method "#{key}=", value do` should be `define_method "#{key}=" do |value|` otherwise a fine answer. Alternatively `->(_,_) {{}}` could be replaced with `proc { {} }` to make the answer less cryptic, but that's just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: I also just realized that you can't access `options` in class context, only in instance context. Meaning that this line would result in an error: `options['details'].default_proc = ->(_,_) {{}}`

Comment: @JohanWentholt Thanks for `do |value|`, sure, updated. For the rest: I never committed to writing the code for free. I just showed the working solution. Where to put the initialization (initializer?) is up to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the key as a parameter as well right?

```
  def get_key key=:key1
   options['details']&.[](key)
  end

  def set_key= value, key=:key1
   options['details'] ||= {}
   options['details'][key] ||=0 
   options['details'][key] += value 
  end
```

Comment: How does this answer a question about creating getters and setters?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple & Short

Depending on re-usability you can choose different options. The short option is to simply define the methods using a loop in combination with [`#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  option_accessors = ['key1', 'key2']

  option_accessors.map(&:to_s).each do |accessor_name|
    #                     ^ in case you provide symbols in option_accessors
    #                       this can be left out if know this is not the case

    define_method accessor_name do
      options.dig('details', accessor_name)
    end

    define_method "#{accessor_name}=" do |value|
      details = options['details'] ||= {}
      details[accessor_name] ||= 0
      details[accessor_name] += value
    end
  end
end
```

## Writing a Module

Alternatively you could write a module that provide the above as helpers. A simple module could look something like this:

```
# app/model_helpers/option_details_attribute_accessors.rb
module OptionDetailsAttributeAccessors
  def option_details_attr_reader(*accessors)
    accessors.map(&:to_s).each do |accessor|
      define_method accessor do
        options.dig('details', accessor)
      end
    end
  end

  def option_details_attr_writer(*accessors)
    accessors.map(&:to_s).each do |accessor|
      define_method "#{accessor}=" do |value|
        details = options['details'] ||= {}
        details[accessor] ||= 0
        details[accessor] += value
      end
    end
  end

  def option_details_attr_accessor(*accessors)
    option_details_attr_reader(*accessors)
    option_details_attr_writer(*accessors)
  end
end
```

Now you can simply extend your class with these helpers and easily add readers/writers.

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  extend OptionDetailsAttributeAccessors

  option_details_attr_accessor :key1, :key2
end
```

If anything is unclear simply ask away in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This was cited as the link for a Phind call that gave me a poor answer. I'd suggest that `store_accessor :column_name` is the optimal way to interface with a flat JSON object in 2024.

It is built to allow you to interact with the JSON column as if it were an association, e.g.,

```
class BusinessProfile < ApplicationRecord
  store_accessor :vcard_details, :website_url, :contacts_array
end
```

Then you can call an instance via `profile.website_url` and set it with `profile.website_url = "https://blah.com`